# Windows Server lagging when running too many program in one user account. But fine when split the total programs to two user account

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2019

I am deploying my application on a windows server 2019 (Intel Xeon, 64GB RAM). My application will communicate with x30 clients using MSMQ. The server start lagging and not responding when 10 of my applications (with total 300+ client communication) is running on a user account. The CPU & RAM utilization is around 10%~20%

However, the server is fine when i split the total application to two user account, where 5 application running in each user account. The CPU & RAM utilization about the same which is around 10%~20%.

Based on my knowledge, the Windows System Resource Manager has been deprecated in window server 2012. Is there other factor causing the resource limitation on one user account? Or should i look in another way?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the application use any common resource that is linked to the user account's folders?

Comment: hi @harrymc, the application will generate log in ..\USER\AppData\MyAppName

Comment: I take it to mean that the log acts to serialize the threads (or processes), so that waiting for access is a problem?